# lisp ceramic: how do I shut the ceramic server down?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have been working through Ceramic tutorials, and they tend to have a workflow like the following:

```
(ql:quickload :ceramic)
(ceramic:setup)
(ceramic:start)
(defvar window (ceramic:make-window :url "https://www.google.com/"
                                    :width 800
                                    :height 600))
(ceramic:show window)
```

As far as I understand, this sets up a host process on my machine in the background that serves the `window` content. That process appears to be backgrounded so that I can still use the sbcl repl while the server is running. How do I turn off the server `(ceramic:stop)` doesn't seem to do the trick -- when I try to run `(ceramic:start)` again, I get an error that the port is already in use.

Comment: Do you have logs after `stop`? I tried and I could call stop and start again (but couldn't re-show the window).

Comment: No I think the action just completes silently.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not just the TCP `TIME_WAIT` 'problem' (it's not a problem: it's a necessary feature of the protocol).  In particular if you wait for a bit can you then restart the thing?